# Codeigniter custom routes to hide controller/page

Tags: php, codeigniter, routes

I got a site to redevelop, it has been written using codeigniter. The URLs for the pages are like www.mysite.com/page/index/mypage and I'd like to change it to www.mysite.com/mypage.
I tried to set custom routes in routes.php but it doesn't work. This is my routes.php:

```
    $route['default_controller'] = "page";
    $route['404_override'] = 'page';

    $route['(.*)/page/index/(.*)']  = 'page/index/$1';
    $route['(.*)'] = 'page/index/$1';
```

Could somebody help, how to configure it.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To go from /page/index/mypage to mypage

```
$route['default_controller'] = "page";
$route['404_override'] = 'page';

$route['/page/(:any)']  = 'page/index/$1';
```

You can also try:

```
 $route['/(:any)']  = 'page/index/$1';
```

You you might have trouble accessing any other urls.